# mapstruct - Update existing bean - ignoring 'id' field in all the child/nested beans (arraylists, sets etc..)

Tags: mapstruct

I have a parent class with many child entities.
There are 2 instances of this parent class.
Want to copy data of 1 instance to another one (ignoring the 'id' property in all the child entities)

---- hiding getters and setters for brevity

```
public class IdBean {
    private Long id;
}

public class City extends IdBean {
    private String name;
}

public class Country extends IdBean {
    private String name;
    private List<City> cities;
}

public class Student extends IdBean {
    private String name;
}

public class School extends IdBean {
    private String name;
    private List<Student> students;
    private List<Country> countries;
}

@MapperConfig(mappingInheritanceStrategy = MappingInheritanceStrategy.AUTO_INHERIT_FROM_CONFIG)
public interface SchoolCentralConfig {

    @Mapping(ignore = true, target = "id")
    IdBean updateBeanEntityFromDto(IdBean dto);
}

@Mapper(config = SchoolCentralConfig.class)
public interface SchoolMapper {
    SchoolMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( SchoolMapper.class );
    @Mapping(target = "companies.id", ignore = true )
    void updateSchoolFromDto(School schoolDTO, @MappingTarget School      schoolEntity);
}
```

I want to ignore all the 'id' property from all the nested fields.

Answer (score 0):

`MappingInheritanceStrategy.AUTO_INHERIT_FROM_CONFIG` does (unfortunately) not work for nested methods yet.

What you can do is write a signature for `Country` and `Student` as well. Then it will work.

So:

```java
@Mapper(config = SchoolCentralConfig.class)
public interface SchoolMapper {
    SchoolMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( SchoolMapper.class );

    void updateSchoolFromDto(School schoolDTO, @MappingTarget School      schoolEntity);

    void updateStudentFromDto(Student studentDTO, @MappingTarget Student      studentEntity);

    // etc

}
```